# Android hide app/activity name on status bar

Tags: java, android, statusbar, android-statusbar

I would like to hide status bar app name and leave only icon. (And add button + spinner but i know how to do it) I search in google and on stackoverflow but the only thing that I found is how to hide whole status bar.

I just want to do something like this:

[Link to screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVHp2.jpg)

Comment: Post your Activity and View XML code. What have you tried already?

Comment: I tried to change *android:label="@string/app_name"* to *android:label=" "* in <application> and <activity> (manifest) but when i do this the name of app disappears in android phone menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem can be solved easily following this actions:

1. Using a empty activity title (you can set the title with a empty string like "")
2. Use a spinner inside Toolbar layout with the spinner that your want.

   ```
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
       android:id="@+id/toolbar"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
       android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
       app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

       <Spinner
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
   </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
   ```
3. Do whatever your want with your spinner. :)

Comment: I tried to change the title in manifest (android:label) but thats change title of app in phone menu too. But when I changed title using "setTitle(" ");" in MainActivity then everything work fine ^^ thanks for showing the way